# Conflict between Tikz and bookmark packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, bookmarks, dvips

I updated the packages in my distribution Latex this week and I lost bookmarks in the pdf :

Compilation with Pdflatex work well but compilation with latex+dvips+ps2pdf break bookmarks on the pdf file.

here is a mimimal exemple :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section{One section}

Some text

\newpage 

\section{Another section}

Another text

\end{document}
```

You can download the pdf file without bookmark [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RLiQP5ICrxpU4ybUooEOKYR2b1OFnABC/view?usp=sharing)

With only `\usepackage{bookmark}` or only `\usepackage{tikz}` it work but not with both.

Does anyone understand what's going on ?

I use Miktex 20.11 and GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3 on windows 8.1

Comment: I can't confirm your problem (tested by pdfLaTeX in MikTeX 20.11, W10). Your MWE works fine, bookmark are visible as expected in Adobe Reader. BTW, `hyperref` package had to be loaded in preamble last. How you compile your document?

Comment: The bug is with compilation latex+dvips+ps2pdf. There is a bug too if i put packages in other order like : 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}

Comment: I can confirm this, but I have no idea yet why they are lost, in the ps they are still there.

Comment: It looks like a ghostscript problem. If I convert the ps with a ps2pdf from texlive 2019 it works fine, with ps2pdf the same ps fails.

Comment: Hm, it could also be an error in the dvips backend of pgf. If I remove a piece of code there, the bookmarks reappear.

Comment: it's interesting. My update contained a pgf update of October 3, 2020. If i use gs9.26 with option  -dSAFER  it works! But not with gs9.53.3

Comment: well the problematic code is from line 107 to 112 in pgfsys-dvips.def, and this is code that obviously has been added to handle the new transparency command of ghostscript. But I have no idea why is leads to ghostscript ignoring the bookmarks.

Comment: I added an issue at pgf https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/944, but it could be that it should be actually reported to ghostscript.

Comment: Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: There will be probably soon an update to the bookmark package with the fix suggested by alexg, which should resolve the problem.

Comment: bookmark has been updated, I hope it works now again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 1.29 2020-11-06 of the bookmark package resolve the problem.